# Failing to construct an HTTP GET request in Go

Tags: http, go

I'm able to get an HTTP GET request to work like so:

```
resp, err := http.Get("https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cves/1.0/?modStartDate=2021-10-29T12%3A00%3A00%3A000%20UTC-00%3A00&modEndDate=2021-10-30T00%3A00%3A00%3A000%20UTC-00%3A00&resultsPerPage=5000")
```

I wanted to have an easier way to construct the query parameters so I created this:

```
  req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cves/1.0/", nil)
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("Error: %v\n", err)
      os.Exit(1)
  }
  q := req.URL.Query()
  q.Set("modStartDate", "2021-10-29T12:00:00:000 UTC-00:00")
  q.Set("modEndDate", "2021-10-30T00:00:000 UTC-00:00")
  q.Set("resultsPerPage", "5000")
  req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()
  client := http.Client{}
  resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

The response status is a 404. It's not clear to me what I'm missing. What is the first GET request doing that I'm missing in the second one?

For reference, the API I'm working with:
https://nvd.nist.gov/developers/vulnerabilities

Comment: Instead of q.Set(), we're using q.Add().  Does that work for you?

Comment: @jcfollower: Still get a 404 when changing to `q.Set()`

Comment: @JimB: manually encoded version works, I get the expected data back. There is no extra `:00` in the time.

Comment: Oh, their format is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS`, so you are missing a time field in the second version (actually reading the error message helps here)

Answer (score 0):

As @JimB noted, comparing your original raw query with your generate query shows the formatting issue:

```
origURL := "https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cves/1.0/?modStartDate=2021-10-29T12%3A00%3A00%3A000%20UTC-00%3A00&modEndDate=2021-10-30T00%3A00%3A00%3A000%20UTC-00%3A00&resultsPerPage=5000"

u, _ := url.Parse(origURL)
q, _ := url.ParseQuery(u.RawQuery)


q2 := url.Values{}
q2.Set("modStartDate", "2021-10-29T12:00:00:000 UTC-00:00")
q2.Set("modEndDate", "2021-10-30T00:00:000 UTC-00:00")
q2.Set("resultsPerPage", "5000")

fmt.Println(q)  // map[modEndDate:[2021-10-30T00:00:00:000 UTC-00:00] modStartDate:[2021-10-29T12:00:00:000 UTC-00:00] resultsPerPage:[5000]]
fmt.Println(q2) // map[modEndDate:[2021-10-30T00:00:000 UTC-00:00] modStartDate:[2021-10-29T12:00:00:000 UTC-00:00] resultsPerPage:[5000]]
```

https://play.golang.org/p/36RNIb7Micu

So add the extra `:00` to your time format:

```
q.Set("modStartDate", "2021-10-29T12:00:00:00:000 UTC-00:00")
q.Set("modEndDate", "2021-10-30T00:00:00:000 UTC-00:00")
```